# Do pub dev packages need to be referenced in your Flutter app's Privacy Policy when publishing on Google Play?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play, publish, pub.dev

I'm publishing a Flutter app on Google Play and in the process of writing its Terms & Conditions, Privacy Policy, EULA, etc. The app relies on several pub dev packages (most with MIT license, except the firebase packages). How do I, and do I need to at all, reference them and their creators in the scope of my app? Should I just list them in my Privacy Policy?

Do I need to reference them at all?

(I'm not publishing the code of the app anywhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is at least an extra widget for this from Flutter to display the copyrights. I think if you somehow make this dialogue accessible in the app, then you are on the safe side.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AboutDialog-class.html